# multiply Bigdecimal and int generating error

Tags: java, android, int, bigdecimal

I have one value like `0.0004` when I store this in `Integer` it is converting into `Exponential` format, So I have used `Bigdecimal` to convert it to normal value like below

```
 Bigdecimal x=BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0004)
```

Now I am trying to multiply as `x*100` but I am getting below error.

```
Error: The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) BigDecimal, int
```

Because of this error if I use this without bigdecimal again it is converting to `EXponential`.

Can any one please suggest me the way to multiply `Bigdecimal and int`.

googled a lot but couldn't find the correct solution.

Thanks for your time

Comment: you need to use x.multiply(something)

Comment: What do you think this is, C++?  Java doesn't overload operators like `*`.  They only work on primitives.  Have you checked the [`BigDecimal` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)?

Comment: when I use `multiply` I am getting this error `The method multiply(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: `x.multiply(new BigDecimal(10));`

Comment: Why don't you use `float` or `double`?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper thanks for your answer.. let me try with double

Comment: @Dawnkeeper i am unable to store the result in Double..giving me the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from BigDecimal to Double`

Comment: You are trying to store a `real number` into an `integer`. This won't work. What exactly are you trying to do with those "0.0004" ?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper my taks is .. `converting bigdecimal to double and then adding with integer and finally storing the value in double variable`. This is my requirement

Comment: Ok. The linked duplicate will do the trick for a simple conversion. But if it is required to work with the whole range of BigDecimal, then you have a problem as BigDecimal is of arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `BigDecimal.multiply` to multiply your `BigDecimal`.

However, the int value of `0.0004 * 100` will be `0`, which is probably not what you want.

Finally, you can alter the how the `BigDecimal` is represented in terms of fractional digits by using a `NumberFormat` instance and formatting your `Number`.

Here's an example:

```
BigDecimal x= BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0004);
BigDecimal y = x.multiply(new BigDecimal("100"));
int z = y.intValue();
System.out.printf("y is %s\tz is %d%n", y, z);
// edit to truncate fractional digits
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.printf("y (2 fraction digits) is %s", nf.format(y));
```

**Output**

```
y is 0.04000    z is 0
y (2 fraction digits) is 0.04
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but I need output as an integer value `0.04`.. how can I achieve?

Comment: @Siva `0.04` is **not** an integer value. `0.04000` is mathematically equivalent to `0.04`.

Comment: I am sorry.. I am totally new to java programming... please suggest me how can I store `0.04` and add it to an `Integer` value and store in another `Integer`

Comment: @Siva it's not about programming but rather about maths. Anyway, I've edited my answer to include a presentational representation of your `0.04` decimal truncated.

Comment: your approach worked but a string value is returned when I tried to change to double using `Double.valueOf` then I am again getting an exponential value between my output is `0.0004` and not `0.04` can you please suggest any wayout. Thanks for your continous support

Comment: I have managed to get the required value without guidence thank you very much.Process I have followed `First multiplied 0.0004 with bigdecimal of 100 then converted to string to get 0.04 then again changed to double`

Comment: @Siva no probs, glad it worked for you

Answer (score 3):

`BigDecimal`'s are objects. They don't have normal operators.

Instead of a normal multiplication operator like `x*10`, you need to call the method `multiply` in BigDecimal:

```
x = x.multiply(new BigDecimal(10));
```

If you want to store it in a new value:

```
BigDecimal n = x.multiply(new BigDecimal(10));
```

And to convert that to a primative:

```
double d = n.doubleValue();
int i = n.intValue();
```

However, if you're trying to use decimals, why not just use a double:

```
double x = 0.0004;
double n = x*100;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. can you please help me out in adding the x to integer and store in another integer value.. I am totally new to java programming. I am sorry if I am asking basic question

Comment: Thanks for your answer but double is also storing value in `Exponential` format